# How to calculate the max array size in firestore

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make same data aggregation in Firestore whit cloud function to save same read...

In this particular case i have users and groups of users. On new user i'm saving name and id in a Array in the user group.

Everything is working perfectly (kudos to all fireStore devs), but those array may and will grow a lot.

I'd like to know if there is an artificial cap on array size or if it works like the binary field (max 1mb), and if there is same way to know when i'm approaching the limit

Comment: Check this doc everything clearly mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)

Comment: An array is stored in a document, so you're limited to the document size.  If you think your arrays will grow past that, you need to use a collection instead.

Comment: This is something you do not save into an array

Comment: The quotas are here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas does not say anything specific about number of entries in array but you have a Maximum size for a document of 1 Mib